# Problems with JSONObject vs JSONArray in Android

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I have a pretty specific problem I guess. I'm using Volley library to get a String response from URL, the response is following:

```
{"email":"imribar@gmail.com","phone":"7(707)111-11-11","family_name":"Жилин","name":"Иван","role":0}
```

I get this response by converting my SQL query array to JSON in PHP

```
    $output=$db->query("SELECT email, phone, family_name, name, role FROM users WHERE email=?", "$email")->fetchArray();

    $json=json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo"$json";
```

What I need to do next is go throught this JSON and insert records to local database in my Android APP. In order to do that, I do following:

```
if(response.contains("email")) {
  testResponse.setText("Response is2: " + response);
    try {
         JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArr.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("User",jsonObj.toString());
    
           User user = new User();
           user.email= jsonObj.getString("email");
           user.phone=jsonObj.getString("phone");
           user.firstName=jsonObj.getString("name");
           user.lastName=jsonObj.getString("family_name");
           user.role=jsonObj.getInt("role");
           user.token="123123123fsadf";
    
          insertUser inewuser = new insertUser();
          inewuser.execute(user);
           }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.i("JSONerror", e.toString());
              }
          }
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
 13:24:59.518 22389-22389/com.local.school I/JSONerror: org.json.JSONException: Value {"email":"imribar@gmail.com","phone":"7(707)111-11-11","family_name":"Жилин","name":"Иван","role":0} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Any idea what I can do on PHP side to change the JSONString (add [], or add a name to an array), or what do I need to do in Android?

Comment: I have validated to JSON VALID (RFC 8259).https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response does not have a json array, only an object. 
Array is something like this.

```
[{
        "email": "imribar1@gmail.com",
        "phone": "7(707)990-77-72",
        "family_name": "Жилин2",
        "name": "Иван2",
        "role": 2
    },
    {
        "email": "imribar@gmail.com",
        "phone": "7(707)990-77-71",
        "family_name": "Жилин",
        "name": "Иван",
        "role": 0
    }
]
```

So remove the  loop and try.

```
if(response.contains("email")) {
  testResponse.setText("Response is2: " + response);
    try {
         
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("User",jsonObj.toString());
    
        User user = new User();
        user.email= jsonObj.getString("email");
        user.phone=jsonObj.getString("phone");
        user.firstName=jsonObj.getString("name");
        user.lastName=jsonObj.getString("family_name");
        user.role=jsonObj.getInt("role");
        user.token="123123123fsadf";
    
        insertUser inewuser = new insertUser();
        inewuser.execute(user);
           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("JSONerror", e.toString());
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a `JsonObjectRequest` instead of `StringRequest` when you call `Volley` in your app. It is almost the same as StringRequest but it gets a `JSONObject` as an answer.

```
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // your cose goes here:
       
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());

       User user = new User();
       user.email= jsonObject.getString("email");
       user.phone=jsonObject.getString("phone");
       user.firstName=jsonObject.getString("name");
       user.lastName=jsonObject.getString("family_name");
       user.role=jsonObject.getInt("role");
       user.token="123123123fsadf";

      insertUser inewuser = new insertUser();
      inewuser.execute(user);


}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO: Handle error

}
});
```

[jsonObjectRequest](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#request-json)

Comment: I do String request to perform String based IFs

Comment: you can get the strings from the Json obj as I wrote for you... you get it now?

Comment: Yes thanks, I was confusing Object and Array, as everywhere in examples they work with arrays, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your json string has a json object as root object, while in code you are using `JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(response);` to parse it as if it were an array. Assuming your used json library, you would have to start parsing the json using:

```java
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

The alternative would be to actually generate a json array (`[...]`) rather than a json object (`{...}`) so that your parsing code will recognise it. The choice you want to make will depend on whether you always send a single json object or whether you want to be able to send multiple json objects (in a json array).